# Bxslider not working properly with jQuery 2.1.1

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use bxSlider on my page and at first when I open a page it doesn't work, but then sometimes when I refresh it starts working. What could be the problem?

custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.news').bxSlider(
        {
            mode: 'vertical',
            minSlides: 4,
            maxSlides: 10,
            ticker: true,
            speed: 40000
        }
    );
});
```

My Page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

...

```
<div class="news">...</div>
```

...

```
<script src="../js/query.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could at least provide the code that you are using and also describe better if you have tried any solution.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Also there are no JavaScript errors in a console window

Comment: add your code in js fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use latest file `bxslider.min.js` version v4.2.5

https://jsfiddle.net/8rxobr6j/2/

Comment: check version on file

Comment: I just downloaded latest 4.2.5 version from GitHub, same problem

Comment: Sorry it was wrong version, thanks